# Java concurrent logging to file

Tags: java, logging, concurrency, error-logging

I'm currently writting a logger (e.g. using the java logger) with which I can log activities (info, errors) to a file. This (static) logger class is used by several threads and processes.

If I have just one log file then the threads get blocked, is this right? So only one thread can write to the file?

Another solution would be to have for each thread a own log file, but this would be a bit messy.

Therefore, I tought about first keeping the log in a stream  (perhaps for each thread one) and only at the end of the program write everything to a file.

Is this the best way? How can I achieve this?

Comment: You could use slf4j, which is a facade to various logger facilities. This allows you to switch out your logging back-end and also provides you with lazily evaluated patterns. Logback as a back end seems to provide asynchronous file appenders.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use any frameworks or libraries.

Comment: I see. So basically, your question is not specific to logging, but you would want to be able to concurrently write to the same file without blocking. If you use Java 7, the `java.nio` package provides you with the right tools as far as I know.

Comment: I looked at NIO for network communication some time ago and it's pretty complicate. ;) How about storing the logs in an stream (keeping them in memory) and writing it at the end to the file? At the end it does not matter if the threads have to wait until they can write.

Comment: Keeping everything in memory and writing at the end may be the way to go if you want to optimize performance. The only drawback I see with this approach currently is, that, if something goes wrong and the application crashes fatally before you can write your log, the entire log is lost. Question is: How much is the gain in performance compared to blocking IO? Especially since you still need synchronization on the stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try writing everything to a file at the end of the program, but this might use a lot of memory, and also loggers usually need to be implemented so that they'll still log most/all of their data in case of a program crash or other unexpected termination.

As an alternative, you can use a concurrent queue for logged messages, e.g. a [LinkedBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) or a [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html), where multiple threads write their messages to the queue and a single thread reads from the queue and writes the messages to a file.  With a `BlockingQueue` the logging thread can call `take` or `poll(timeout, TimeUnit)` on the queue, causing the thread to sleep until a messages becomes available; with a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` you can have the logging thread sleep for, say, ten seconds, then wake up, flush the queue to the file, and go back to sleep for another ten seconds.  In either case the threads generating the logged messages won't block.